# loop through the values of a particular column in datatable

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with some values in it, all I want to do is loop through the values of a particular column and write a query to retrieve data from database. what am trying to say is that, the values I want to collect from the datatable is groupid, so I want to retrieve all the group names that is in the database with the group id provided. Here is my code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                object cellData = row["Group ID"];
                int ac = Convert.ToInt32(cellData);

                var data = (from o in db.groups where o.groupid == ac select new { o.groupname });
                GridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
```

The code after looping will get only the last value and ignore others. I don't know how to write the code so it can loop through the datatable and get the list of group name from database with all the id provided in the datatable

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to join the group name to the dataset when initially calling for the data instead of trying to do so after the fact? Anyway, the reason why you only see the last value is because you reset the value each time with the new call to get the group. Nowhere outside of your loop do you save the data gathered, So setup a datatable, add the results to it, then after the loop set it to your grid

Comment: @zuckerburg please show me how

Comment: Are you not loading the names too in the grid?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the datatable only have groupid, I have to load the names from a table in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume here that datatable `dt` is populated by some other way.

You are looping thru the rows of `dt` try to get the data from database for each of the row and bind it to the grid. that's why you are getting only the last data in the grid.

You first need to create the collection for `Gropup ID` from the `dt` and then query the database for all those `Group ID` in the collection.

```
var groupIds = new List<int>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // Get and convert the "Group ID" from the row to integer
    // Add it to the list.
    groupIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["Group ID"].ToString()));
}

// Query database to filter for all the groupids in the list.
var data = (from o in db.groups where groupsIds.Contains(o. groupid) select new { o.groupname });
GridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.

Comment: That's pretty awesome work, thanks alot, it works perfect